# Change of direction of a massless particle

Tags: special-relativity

Novice with little mathematical prowess.
1a - Is it reasonable to consider a massless particle (photon) as a 2 dimensional entity with no dimension in the direction of travel, as seen by any observer not in its reference frame?
1b - if so, then, if the particle is reflected at an angle from some surface, is there a paradox in a 2 dimensional entity effectively 'bending' in the 3rd dimension during reflection (as viewed in the observers frame)?

2 - If a photon is reflected back along its path, is there a point where its instantaneous velocity is zero, and isn't this dissallowed?

Comment: *"as seen by any observer not in its reference frame?"* - a massless particle doesn't have a (inertial) reference frame since it isn't at rest in any inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A photon is point-like. That is to say it's a *zero* dimensional object: it has no spatial extent.

Photons don't actually reflect when they hit something. They are absorbed and a new photon is emitted. So no photon is ever stopped.